# What tree is this?

Tags: identification, trees

What is this tree?

[image: unknown blue flower tree]

It looks a bit like a lavender but it doesn't really have a scent (and it's a tree!).

Comment: what zone or location in the world?

Comment: Simple leaves? Not compound like a Jacaranda?: https://www.google.com/search?q=jacaranda&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis0er1ndzMAhVMMz4KHbs8Cc0Q_AUIBygB&biw=1089&bih=638

Comment: one closeup  picture of the foliage is all that is needed to confirm that it is a jacaranda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a Ceanothus - as to which variety, I can't tell from the photograph (because I can't see the leaves properly), except to say its one of the larger varieties - Ceanothus vary in height from around 5 feet up to around 20 feet, some are evergreen some are not, other varieties have larger, looser and paler blue flowers later in the year. If you'd like to add a close up photograph showing both a flower in detail and the leaves, it should be possible to refine the ID.

Comment: Must be nice to live where ceoanthus can get larger.  C Americanus is the only one to grow on my zone, three feet if the winter is mild

Comment: @kevinsky - they get large here in the UK, but they have the unfortunate habit of being short lived, so may suddenly keel over without warning after 8 to 10 years, and will not tolerate a very cold winter at all. I guess they're not known as Californian Lilac for nothing... and to be honest, on a cold, grey, cloudy day when the flowers are out, they can look pretty depressing (in the UK), but lovely when the sun is on them